# Page too long (used sticky-footer)

Tags: css

Hi~ I'm making an art portfolio online and I've run into an issue. I've used sticky footer ryanfaitdotcom/sticky-footer/ and now my page seems unnecessarily long. Any advice would be appreciated!

Here's the code:

deleted because it's wrong. correct code can be found on bottom

or here:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>





</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrap" class="group">
        <div id="main-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut </p>
        </div> <!-- End main-content --> 
    </div> <!-- End page-wrap --> 
    <div class="push"></div>
</div> <!-- End wrapper --> 
<div class="footer">        
    <img src="Images/organicspahouston_logo.png" width="400" height="238" />
    <div class="bottom">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

with style.css

```
* {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
html { height: 100%; background:#B5A9A0 url(../Images/osh_pic_bg1.png) no-repeat;     background-size: 100%}
body { height: 100%; font: RomulC; font-size: 12px; color:#A39E95; text-align: center } 

article, aside, figure, footer, header, nav, section { display: block; }

.group:after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }
.group { display: inline-block; clear: both; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/ * html .group { height: 1%; } .group { display:    block; } /* close commented backslash hack */

.wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto -258px;
}

#page-wrap { width:800px; -moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px; margin: 175px auto; background:#000; position:relative;}

#main-content { float:right; width: 640px; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px; -moz-border-  radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px; background: #2D261C; position: relative; padding: 10px 0px 0px    0px; }

.footer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto 0;
padding: 0;
text-align:center;
    height: 258px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.footer img {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
} 
.bottom {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
margin: 0 auto 0;
padding: 0;
text-align:center;
background-color: #000000;
}

.bottom a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: underline;
border: 0;
}

.bottom p {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 4px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
color: #fff;
font: 0.8em arial,sans-serif;
}


</html>
```

and layout.css from sticky footer

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 800px;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -258px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's    height */
}
.footer {
height: 258px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
} 

.push {
height: 258px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*
```

@Samich provided me with the solution below (plus helped me immensely with cleaning things up). I was adding margin, but I had to add it to BOTH sides so it went from:

```
#page-wrap { width:800px; -moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px; margin: 175px auto; background:#000; position:relative;}
```

to

```
#page-wrap { width:800px; -moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px; margin: 175px auto Opx; background:#000; position:relative;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kagawa_leah/c2N24/11/

What a difference a 0 makes.

Comment: That fiddle is nonsensical. It's just a blank white page in the view panel with a single line of text.

Comment: You have no selector for the push div, it's meant to be the same height as your footer!

Comment: @Jarred Farrish You're right! I the link.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks were you pointing out the negative value for the .push? I've fixed that, plus I added in the lines suggested below. The page still seems a bit long. I have my logo tied to the footer, and as it is, you have to scroll down just to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `height` of your footer and `margin-bottom` of your wrapper to the same value. In your case it's `4em.`

http://jsfiddle.net/WqNEj/3/

**P.S.**
    http://jsfiddle.net/WqNEj/8/

I've set `overflow:hidden` in the footer because it's height 260px which is bigger than footer height.

Comment: I did what you suggested and updated the fiddle and the above.  It still seems a bit long. I also noticed that I had a negative value for the .push. Any other suggestions? Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: First off all you have set: `html, body { height: 800px; }` which should be 100%. Second your footer if 258px height and you will see white space at the bottom, because content of the footer is smaller. And third your content inside `wrapper` is begger than it fits into screen - so it causes scroll.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for your time. I've changed the html,body height. I understand what you're saying about the footer height, it was actually a problem I was having earlier, but the footer height is correct based on the image placed there. You say the content inside the .wrapper is bigger than fits my screen? What part? I'm not worried about scrolling sideways. Why does it scroll down? I would like to position everything on the page like http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/. http://jsfiddle.net/kagawa_leah/c2N24/5/

Comment: I really appreciate all the time and effort you're providing me. I actually have what you wrote, but I think I found the root of my problem. I have a #page-wrap with a margin: 175px that's pushing both the container AND the footer down. How do I keep the #page-wrap where it is without it affecting the footer? http://jsfiddle.net/kagawa_leah/c2N24/10/ that's where i'm at right now with the #page-wrap stuck at the top

Comment: `<!--layout.css-->
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}` here is the problem. In css comments should be `/* */`. You just putted html comment.

Comment: Also, revert back style of the `#page-wrap`. Just change margin from `175px auto` to `175px auto 0` to remove margin from the bottom.

Comment: Thank  you so much! That fixed it! Actually, for the layout.css I had that in a different file but jsfiddle has no option to use two different scripts, and you were right to assume that I didnt know how to mark comments. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! I would vote up, but i dont think i have enough points!

Answer (score 0):

.push must be the same height as your footer , but negative: Set .push to margin-bottom: -258px